# How can I rewrite this to C?

Tags: java, c

how can I rewrite this to C?

```
prefix + str.charAt(i)
```

and

```
str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, len)
```

I tried something like this, but it's failed on `str[3]`

```
int len;
//prefix
len = strlen(prefixP);
char prefix[len];
strncpy(prefix, prefixP, len);

//str
len = strlen(strP);
char str[len+1];
strncpy(str, strP, len);

//prefix + znak
len = strlen(prefix) + 1;
char buffer[len];
sprintf(buffer,"%s%s", prefix, str[3]);

printf("%s, %s, %s\n", prefix, str, buffer);
```

and

```
//str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, len)
char subbuff[i+2];
memcpy(subbuff, str, i+1);
subbuff[i + 1] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", subbuff);

//substring 2
char subbuff2[abs(i-len) + 2];
memcpy(subbuff2, str, abs(i-len) + 1);
subbuff[i + 1] = '\0';*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *substring(char *outbuff, const char *string, size_t start, size_t end){
    size_t len = end - start;//It does not include characters `end` position.
    strncpy(outbuff, string + start, len);
    outbuff[len] = '\0';
    return outbuff;
}

int main(){
    char *prefix = "the ";
    char *str = "not a list";
    char result[32];
    char sub1[16], sub2[16];
    int i = 4, len = strlen(str);
    //prefix + str.charAt(i)
    sprintf(result, "%s%c", prefix, str[i]);
    printf("%s\n", result);//the a

    //str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, len)
    strncpy(sub1, str, i);
    sub1[i] = '\0';
    strncpy(sub2, str + i + 1, len - (i+1));
    sub2[len - (i+1)] = '\0';
    sprintf(result, "%s%s", sub1, sub2);
    printf("%s\n", result);//not  list

    sprintf(result, "%s%s", substring(sub1, str, 0, i), substring(sub2, str, i+1, len));
    printf("%s\n", result);//not  list

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `snprintf` to write to a char buffer of predefined size:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *str = "book keeper";
    const char *prefix = "A nice ";
    char buffer[40];
    int i, n;

    // str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1, len)
    i = 4;
    n = snprintf(buffer, 40, "%.*s%s", i, str, str + i + 1);
    printf("'%s'\n", buffer);

    // prefix + str.charAt(i)
    i = 3;
    n = snprintf(buffer, 40, "%s%c", prefix, str[i]);
    printf("'%s'\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The `%s` format prints a given string, until a `'\0'` character is found. You can add w width like so `%.20s` (note the dot) to print at most 20 charactes. If the width is an asterisk `%.*s`, you have to pass the width as an `int` argument to `snprintf` before passing the string. That means that `substr(str, start, len) can be coded as:

  ```
  snprintf(buf, buflen, "%.*s", str + start, len);
  ```
- You should check the size of the buffer. `snprintf` passes the buffer length along with the buffer itself and guarantees that it is not overwritten. It also returns the number of characters that would have been written if the buffer were big enough.
- If you have to deal with strings of arbitrary length, you can call `snprintf` with a zero buffer length just to see how much space you need and then allocate accordingly. (Don't forget to add one for the terminating `'\0'`.
- Doing all operations in one go with `snprintf` saves you the hassle of appending and concatenating while at the same time keeping track of buffer sizes.
- The character at a certain position `i` in a string `str` can be obtained by reading from the char array: `str[i]`. To write a character with `snprintf`, use the `%c` format.